# HOw to get url contents of weblink

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-applications

SUppose I have a web application which userID is required to pass

Weblink of the previous page is

http://app1.faceicicle.com/admin/entryAction.do?action=first&locale=&sessionID=5q2m04k9c5362p50b17b63p53679jx25&login=8121support&prjLinkURL=&moduelType=&reminderLink=&toModule=&toProject=

How to get the value of the user ID , session ID or the password ?

Comment: Based solely on that url of the previous page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access such parameters by accessing the query string property of the response object

```
Request.QueryString;
```

For an example, check out [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx#Y0)

However, from a security perspective, you may want to have user Id and password passed over in a form rather than url parameters